# Why doesn't nitric oxide react with water?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, water, pnictogen

Why doesn't $\ce{NO}$ (nitric oxide) react with water? I know it is a neutral oxide, but I'm really curious as to why that is. Why will $\ce{NO}$ not react with $\ce{H2O}$?

Comment: Why would it? Normally we explain why things happen, and not why they don't.

Comment: Think about it, oxides dissolve in water to give their corresponding acids or bases. Here, what acid would you get, and how stable would its conjugate base ? i believe now you have your answer

Comment: @IvanNeretin what is "normal"?

Answer (score 6):

Although nitric oxide is thermodynamically unstable, it is kinetically stable as its decomposition rate is very slow<sup>[ref]</sup> and so it is considered stable and won't normally react to anything.

So, nitric oxide wouldn't normally hydrolyze easily. But in the presence of air, it forms [nitrous acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrous_acid) $(\ce{HONO})$:

$$\ce{4NO + O2 + 2 H2O -> 4 HNO2}$$

However, nitrous acid is very unstable and quickly disproportionates:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{2 HNO2 &-> NO2 + NO + H2O &(cold dil. soln.)}\\
\ce{3 HNO2 &-> HNO3 + 2 NO + H2O &(warm conc. soln.)}
\end{align}$$

Since $\ce{HNO2}$ is required to prepare [diazonium salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diazonium_compound) (a versatile compound in organic chemistry), it is prepared in-situ by reaction of $\ce{NaNO2}$ and $\ce{HCl}$. Due to its instability, it is prepared for one-time use and is not stored for further preparations.

---

**Reference:** *J. Phys. Chem.*, **1958**, *62* (3), pp 360–361 https://doi.org/10.1021/j150561a030

Answer (score 0):

I have also heard about a disproportion reaction which happens with a productivity of around $0,01 \%$ as,

$$\ce{4NO + H2O -> N2O + 2HNO2}$$

Comment: Hi thanks for your contribution. Though in such cases, it's much better to cite your source as well. A research paper or a famous textbook generally works. Thanks!

Comment: My chemistry teacher, a professor at my university told me about this reaction a long long time ago. Since then the only source where I could find this reaction was a Russian website which also contains a vast database of known chemical reactions. There is no original source, there's a mistake (HNO3 instead of HNO2) and the only note is "almost no reaction". Sorry, it's a really interesting reaction and I keep wondering about its mechanism but I just fail to find any papers or books, at least on the Internet.

Comment: No worries, and I appreciate your response. But in this case, I think it's rather better if you instead ask a new question, looking for proper citation for the reaction. We support [tag:reference-request] as well, so it wouldn't be a problem :-)